# Is This Proof of Existence and a Solution to P=NP Problem?

Tags: existence

P =/= NP Proof (The Theory of Everything)

Polynomial time problems are known to problems exist. Assume Existence exists. By definition everything in existence is in existence. This means nothing can’t exist. Therefore the concept of not or non, can’t exist, as this implies non existence. This means that Nondeterministic-polynomial time problems can’t exist. Existence can’t equal non-existence. Thus, P=/=NP. As a result, there is only P. Thus a paradox P=NP & P=/=NP. The concept of not exists. Therefore not exists and is a part of everything. Thus a paradox P=NP & P=/=NP. Everything is and isn't. However, everything can't be and not be at the same time. Therefore there needs to to exist a reality where everything is and a reality where everything isn't! Therefore there are 2 realities! However, there also needs to exist a reality where paradoxes are true because paradoxes are included in everything. Therefore, there are 3 realities. One where P=NP, one where P=/=NP, and one where both exist at once. The other can't exist because both p=np and p=/=np are false. Making true nothingness.

(By the way, this is also The Theory of Everything)

I have a book where I published this finding where I'm trying to get the word out.

~Michael Barry “I Got Clap But Im Not A Clapper”

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91700/discussion-on-question-by-michael-barry-is-this-proof-of-existence-and-a-solutio).

Answer (score 6):

This proof cannot possibly be correct, because it doesn't use any properties of P or NP, except perhaps that NP involves some kind of negation.  Thus, if the proof were correct, it would also imply the exact same thing for PSPACE vs NPSPACE.  But we actually know that PSPACE=NPSPACE by Savitch's theorem.  (See, e.g., here: http://www.cs.nthu.edu.tw/~wkhon/lectures/lecture23.pdf)

Comment: You're mistaken. P is a property of everything.

Comment: @present Please help the poster and the readers by expanding on your answer.

Comment: I have expanded it as requested.

Comment: Interesting. Let me think on this. Are there any other similar problems that you can think of also?